# Webstorm and testacular integration

Tags: node.js, webstorm, karma-runner

### What is the simplest way to integrate **WebStorm** and **Testacular**?

I'm trying the **angular-phonecat** tutorial from AngularJs official website and until now i wasn't able to make WebStorm start the Testacular server.

And as far as i researched, there's no such information on the web...

Any guesses?

Comment: There is a related feature request for WebStorm: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-645.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic WebStorm Testacular integration is described here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI&feature=player_embedded#t=459s .

Comment: There is no "NodeJS" configuration item in the list. What to do?

Comment: @Paul, install NodeJS plugin from the Plugin Repository.
Open Settings dialog, select there Plugins item.